# How to create static library

Tags: ios, xcode6

How to create Static libraries using *Xcode 6* and it should support *armv7, armv7s and arm64*.

The libarary should support for devices 4s to latest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you facing? I have followed the steps given on http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial and it worked for Xcode5. I am not sure about Xcode6. However if should work in Xocde6 too.

Comment: What is the purpose of the title you clearly only ask about xcode6 and nothing to do with xcode 5 so why have you included xcode 5. Also this has nothing to do with iOS directly it is xcode related.